# How to make a number increment animation similar to twitter's post like counter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to create an animation similar to Twitter's post like counter (the effect that occurs when you liked a post - the flipping numbers)
I want that same animation. I tried everything I can, I couldn't get it to work.
Here's what I tried

```js
$(function () {
  $('#test').click(function () {
     var $text = $(this).text();
     $(this).addClass('up');
     $(this).text($text + 1);
     $(this).toggleClass('up down');
     $(this).toggleClass('down static');
  });
});
```

```css
  .up {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
      transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .down {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  .static {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
      transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test" class=""> 1 </button>
```

But this didn't work.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For the animation look here: https://erikmartinjordan.com/animation-counter

And for your code can try using a number that increase by 1 when clicked to fix your current counter:

```js
$(function () {
  var $number = 1
  $('#test').click(function () {
     var $text = $(this).text()
     $number = $number + 1
     $(this).text($number)
  });
});
```

```css
.up {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
      transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .down {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  .static {
      display: inline-flex;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
      transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test" class=""> 1 </button>
```

Comment: This does not animate at all.

Comment: @Sean at least counts. and it counts up. he asked for an animation but the code didn't worked so i fixed his code

Comment: @AnonHexo Thanks for fixing the code, but how do I go with the animation part?

Comment: @Chris https://erikmartinjordan.com/animation-counter this may be the answer  to your question

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort, I've gone through the link you sent, but that tutorial is written in React ( which i know nothing about) so I don't know how to convert to jQuery.